# What is the meaning of || and F in this equation?

Tags: notation, least-squares

In this chapter on Least Square Problems: http://www4.ncsu.edu/~mtchu/Teaching/Lectures/MA529/chapter4.pdf in (4.2) there is the following formula:

$$g(x_1,\ldots,x_n):=\sum_{i=1}^m\lVert y_i-f(z_i;x_1,\ldots,x_n)\rVert_F^2\tag{4.2}$$

1. They use ||, I thought it should be the absolute of `yi-f(...)` but I thought that was denoted with a single `|`, does this mean something else?
2. At the end under the square root they write `F`, what does this mean?

Comment: $\|x\|$ is the **norm** (length) of a vector. Because $y_i$ is not an element of $\mathbb R$, you cannot speak of $|y_i|$, but you can still speak of its norm.

Comment: $\|A\|$ means the "[norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space)" of the object $A$.  There are **many** different norms.  To specify which norm we are referring to, we will use subscripts after the norm in case it is not clear.  For example $\|v\|_2$ would refer usually to the euclidean norm that you are used to.  In this case, $\|y\|_F$ is referring to the norm of $y$ according to whatever norm is defined on the normed space $(F,\|\cdot\|)$

Comment: @JMoravitz I'd bet here it is the Froebenius norm ($\lVert\cdot\rVert_F$ is typically used for it). Also, Niek: before going to Chapter 4: looking at Chapter 1, where [they set notation](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~mtchu/Teaching/Lectures/MA529/chapter1.pdf), might not be a bad idea.

Comment: @ClementC. Indeed it is, and the text even says so explicitly at the bottom of page two.  A prime example of why it is always a good idea to look through earlier chapters to see what a notation or phrase means if you do not recognize it to see if it was defined earlier.